# Chose grouping based on parameter in Hibernate named query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have a Hibernate Named Query that I've defined in an XML configuration.

The query generates an aggregate report on person's demographic information. Where we live, that person could live in a province or a county.

I'm wondering if it's possible to aggregate the query by either province or county, based on a hibernate query parameter.

Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT to_char(case when :groupReportBy = 'province' then PROVINCE else COUNTY end),
     COUNT(distinct PERSON_TABLE.PERSON_ID) as {personReport.numOfPeople}
     --, There are some other aggregation things that happen here as well
FROM 
  PERSON_TABLE PI
WHERE
  PI.BDATE >= date '2014-01-01' and PI.BDATE <= date '2014-12-31'
GROUP BY 
  case when :groupReportBy = 'province' then PROVINCE else COUNTY end);
```

The parameter name is :groupReportBy. This query will work if I hard code 'province' instead of the parameter name but If I run it as it appears above, I get the following error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I execute the query from my Java code like this:

```
private List getReport (String namedQuery, String groupReportBy) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.getNamedQuery(namedQuery);

    query.setParameter("reportBy", reportBy);

    return query.list();
}
```

I'm using an Oracle Database.

I'd really prefer not to have to re-write these queries using the Criteria API. They're actually super duper long and there's a lot of them.

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Comment: I'd start with removing extra _closing parenthesis_ at the end of your query (probably remains of _copy/paste_ rom the `to_char` fragment in `select`).

Answer (score 0):

I've never tested it with group parameters, but I assume it behaves the same as with other parts of a JPQL / HQL query.
NamedQueries are precompiled, so cannot be changed later on except for arguments.

I took a 2 mins look into the JPA specification, but didn't find an exact definition what can be modified during runtime. So the following is probably not 100% correct, but should be enough for you.

JPQL/HQL Keywords and model object attributes can not be changed during runtime in a NamedQuery the reason for this is probably that the query gets transformed into an object based representation. So it will be necessary for you to write a standard JPQL/HQL query.